# Can my mouse have virus and infect other machines?

Tags: virus, infection

[This](http://www.amazon.in/DragonWar-ELE-G7-Bluetrack-Gaming-Function/dp/B00IJ69B0M) is my mouse. I used it with my old computer which was full of viruses.

If I use this mouse for my new PC, can my new computer be infected from my mouse?

Comment: Usb-devices are vulnerable to the BadUSB exploit.

Comment: How do you know it's a regular mouse? 

A mouse is a USB device. Could you tell the difference if it wasn't just a mouse but also contained malicious devices?

Comment: c't (a German computer Magazin) once discovered mice offered as gifts were reacting to signs on mousepads. These mice then tried to send keyboard strokes to the computer. Of course the article is only in German and you can only read part if [it](http://www.heise.de/ct/ausgabe/2014-8-Computermaeuse-laden-Schaedlinge-aus-dem-Netz-nach-2156334.html).

Comment: If the USB device was dodgy to begin with, for example: http://thehackernews.com/2014/11/china-made-e-cigarette-chargers-could_26.html

Comment: @idmean: the article you linked was an april fool. This does, however, not change that it is theoretically possible for mice to carry arbitrary payloads. ;)

Comment: If someone could modify your mouse then of course: http://lifehacker.com/5653115/put-a-usb-dongle-inside-your-mouse-for-hidden-storage .

Comment: Hey, that mouse has a Marco function! I wonder if that could be exploited in a similar way that a macro function could be exploited? Maybe it could click at the expected coordinates of a Windows start menu, hover around to get to a CMD prompt, and then right-click paste something interesting?

Comment: In fact, you could easily weaponize this mouse to do just that, and then leave it for someone to find at work/school.

Comment: A real, living mouse would be more effective to use.... Just sayin'

Comment: @DanRoss - but the mouse doesn't know anything about the screen coordinates. It just sends info to the computer which tells how the mouse has been moved left-right and/or forward-backward. Frankly I think the easiest way to weaponize a mouse would be to pack it with mercury fulminate. (KIDS! DON'T TRY THIS AT HOME!! THESE PEOPLE ARE PROFESSIONALS!!!)

Comment: It could move itself -10000,-10000 and then assume that it is at 0,0, and assume that the monitor is 1920x1080. That would often work.

Comment: Or it would know that it most likely starts out at the center of the screen, because that is where Windows places the mouse pointer on boot. Hitting screen edges during use would still be a problem, but probably not an insurmountable one.

Answer (score 82):

USB devices as a rule, in principle, can carry viruses. But that doesn't mean that *all* USB devices are capable of carrying viruses, it just means that if you don't know where the device came from, then it you shouldn't plug it into your computer even if it doesn't *look* like a device that could transmit a virus.

That said, most mice (presumably including this one) don't contain any writable memory. So the mouse can't be modified by an infected computer. So if the mouse wasn't dangerous to begin with, then plugging it into a dangerous computer generally can't *make* it a dangerous mouse.

---

Interestingly, this particular mouse is unusual in that it *does* actually have some amount of memory in the form of [programmable macros](http://www.dragonwar.jp/product-detail.php?id=19), actually stored on-device. This makes the device slightly more suspect -- a malicious piece of software could theoretically overwrite your macros. How that might translate into subversive behavior is anyone's guess, but for run-of-the-mill malware infections, transmission by way of this particular macro function is quite unlikely, if for no other reason than because this mouse is not very common.

There's some chatter about the possibility of overwriting the mouse's firmware so as to persist an attack. Flashing firmware was the basis for the [Bad USB](https://srlabs.de/badusb/) attack class. But this requires that the firmware be user-flashable. For most mice there's nothing to worry about. Adding a firmware modification feature to the USB connection is expensive and uncommon. But if you expect to see such a feature anywhere, it would be on overly complicated and expensive peripherals targeted at gamers.

The anatomy of such an attack would be, almost certainly, to emulate a keyboard and inject a script of keystrokes when you're not looking -- see the [USB Rubber Ducky](http://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe?variant=353378649) for how this works.

Comment: Modern mice tend to have writable firmware. Even the cheap pieces may be infectable - and the chance goes up for the more expensive ones. There's not a lot of space for any modern virus (disk formatters are kind of rare now :)), but we're living on the internet now - it's quite possible to fit in enough code to allow a HTTP download and run whatever executable. IIRC mouse drivers aren't kernel-mode anymore, but it's still a vulnerability (especially without UAC). Of course, it's still not very likely - it's too much effort on the wannabe-hacker's part.

Comment: @Luaan Not to mention that each "hack" must be for a very specific device, firmware version, model, manufacturer, driver version, operating system and operating system version and build and hardware architecture and it's version. Just too many variables for someone to even try it.

Comment: A mouse with the correct software could pretend to be a keyboard and send keystrokes to download and run software using common keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel But it could be used to target a specific victim, e.g. to enter a protected environment/network. [USB sticks have been left in parking lots to do this](http://www.wired.com/2011/06/the-dropped-drive-hack/), and a mouse would seem even more innocent.

Comment: @Joe Sounds like a good solution, but only if left innactive for a few moments. If someone is around the computer, that one will throw the device away.

Comment: @dtech I think that only works with deep knowledge of the system.

Comment: @Luaan [Citation Needed]. Mice tend to have microcontrollers, microcontrollers have firmware. But mice don't typically have a mechanism to overwrite that firmware over the USB connection; you would have to connect the uC through its standard programming interface, which is, as a rule, not accessible to a computer over USB.

Comment: @tylerl every micro I have worked with has some way to access the memory bus over USB. Also your assertion that "most mice (presumably including this one) don't contain any writable memory" is almost certanly wrong.

Comment: @Sam: Not PICs (which are actually quite popular in the peripheral markets). The common PIC18 USB controllers are not normally flashable from USB unless you deliberately write your firmware to do it (basically, you need to write your own Flashing protocol). Most PICs in production do not enable program memory write instead relying on the special high voltage programming mode to flash program memory. In which case, without special hardware you can't flash the PIC even if you have access to the programming pins.

Comment: @Sam to add to slebetman's comment: it's not just the PIC. The AVR isn't typically USB-flashable nor is the MSP430 (unless you add that feature yourself). Typically micros that can be flashed via USB out-of-the-box are designed for hobbyists, not professionals. The Arduino, for example, can be written over USB, but it has specific hardware and firmware added for that purpose; the underlying AVR on its own doesn't support that feature.

Answer (score 25):

According to my post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/976201/mechanical-mouse-and-memory-storage), the memory of a mouse is too small to store a virus (plus, it is a read only memory). So in practice it is very difficult to get a mouse infected.

But still there have been a few cases where a mouse was used as an attack vector to infect not only one computer but a whole network thanks to the firmware contained within it that is automatically launched when the mouse is plugged to a computer. ([Netragard’s Hacker Interface Device (HID)](https://www.netragard.com/netragards-hacker-interface-device-hid))

Comment: Don't most mice contain a microprocessor, which *does* have memory?

Comment: Depends on which type of mouse you talk about. If you are considering the *normal* mouse (the one with a ball, if I may say so), the answer is no. If you are talking about optic mice, the answer is yes, they have a processor integrated into an ASIC that drives a camera that takes pictures of a surface, records them to memory, and compares them against newer pictures and decides in which direction the device was moved. But the memory is too small to contain a malware as I said. The example I gave in my answer is about a mouse fabricated for the purpose to harm a client of Nefragard. @Bergi

Comment: I didn't mean the image processor of optical mice, I meant the interface controller (required for both USB and PS/2). How simplicistic that might be built, whether/how their firmware can be updated, and how much space is needed for malware might differ. Of course, including a whole USB hub and custom hacking device in the article you linked offers more possibilities :-)

Comment: @Bergi Actually, the memory is the main interesting element as it is needed to store the malware if you want to use a mouse as an attack vector but I read in practice it is too small to handle such *big amount* of data.

Comment: @Begueradj: As Luuan commented above, a few keystrokes to open a console, download a file and execute it would suffice. Indeed, storing the whole file on the mouse is unlikely possible.

Comment: Do you have any justification or evidence for your statement that most mice do not have any memory? See [Luuan's comment](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100743/can-my-mouse-have-virus-and-infect-other-machines#comment174271_100749) that most mice have writeable firmware.

Comment: @D.W. I did not say a mouse does not have a memory: neither in my answer nor in my comments

Comment: Huh?  You write in the very first sentence of your answer that "Most mice do not have any type of memory.", but you claim you didn't say that?  I don't follow you.  Did you not write the answer that appears above your name?  Sounds like you need to edit your answer to be a lot clearer about what you are and aren't saying.

Comment: @D.W. Yes. I am using a normal mouse (ball mouse, if this is how it is called), and I think they are the most used (at least regarding my direct environment, but I have no statistics about that). Such mouse does not have a memory.

Comment: Again, I suggest that you edit your answer to clarify what you are trying to say, what the rationale for your statement is, and what assumptions you are making.  Your answer says "Most mice", but now your comments suggest that maybe you are really talking about "Ball mice" and assuming that most mice are "ball mice".  The right solution is not to continue with a back-and-forth in comments; the right solution is to edit your answer to be more explicit.  P.S. I still would like to see what is the reason for claiming ball mice don't have writeable firmware.  Do you have any evidence for that?

Answer (score 9):

The mouse you have linked contains a macro function,  it *could* be used for malicious purposes, but a specific set of programmed inputs would need to be configured for a very specific attack on your environment, additionally the 6 buttons would need to be mapped to inputs as well.

The biggest risk would be any software that you install with the mouse which allows you to configure your mouse key mappings and programme the macros.

Although unlikely it not unheard for commercially available products to come packed with software that has secondary functions that you may not be aware of and could be considered malicious. The software itself could also contain vulnerabilities, that could be exploitable.

The real risks with any mice, keyboards or any other human interface device (HID) are the associated vectors which may be left exposed.

For example HID USB ports are typically left open, especially for a mouse and keyboard, even on assests that have USB interfaces locked down. These interfaces can be used with commercially avaliable products like the USB Rubber Ducky for malicious purposes. Additionally modified mice like Netragard USB project can also be used to attack a system.

Intermediary hardware devices could also be used to capture mouse inputs.

Additional vectors such as sniffing any radio communications on wireless mice and keyboards is also possible, but would require special hardware within close proximity.

Then there is the old spy movie stuff, mice tampered with to place trackers, microphones, loggers, etc, inside them. How much this has a place in reality I don't know, regardless the risk associated with it for most people is very low.

These are generic to all mice though and not just the one you linked to.

TLDR; Your mouse has a low risk of being used maliciously.  Mice in general *could* be used to deliver malicious payloads, but the biggest risks with them is the associated attack vectors which *may* be exposed. Although the risk attached is low and typically physical access is required.

Comment: Most macro-function devices I'm aware of don't actually reprogram the device, they just tell the driver/controller to execute some additional function.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely and the mouse in question appears to operate exactly as you describe. This is the reason I highlighted the software that the mouse will use to operate.

Comment: Yeah, but for the PC-side program to have any bearing in that case you'd have to transfer the data somehow, at which point you're asking "I transferred program data from A to B, could I be compromised".  The macro function itself is a red herring, and is unlikely to be an additional vector when moving to a new machine.  Telling the macro to execute an attack (say, open a command prompt) would require the same access as actually executing the attack, so isn't interesting.  Distributing a malicious profile would work better, since most people don't check them like .bat files...

Comment: I don't disagree.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: theoretically, mice can be an infection vector if we assume that someone get their computer infected, then he reformatted the computer, thinking it'll get him to clean slate, but as soon as the user plugged the mouse in and pressed the right trigger, the mouse seems a series of mouse and keyboard pressed and the infection is back. Yes it is rather convoluted, so in practice, it's unlikely to be used.

Comment: @LieRyan - Unlikely.  As most of the other answers are pointing out, basic mice aren't usually reprogrammable (I'm ignoring a straight up factory-made-malicious device, which wouldn't need you to do more than plug it in).  Macro-enabled mice are dependent on PC-side programs and special drivers for that functionality (all of them, I assume), and aren't reprogrammable either.  Ergo, the mouse itself is incapable of being the vector.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse to support your point in *only some cases*: my macro-capable mouse is at home but my bluetooth presenter sends <winkey>+{ and <winkey>+} for it's programmable buttons, the software then carries out macros (limited testing as I use it on linux and don't have the windows CD here).  *However* the mouse (a logitech G300) can be configured to send key combinations using the windows software, which then work under linux with no drivers.  I don't think it can send sequences, but assigning "<winkey>+t;  rm -rf ~/" would be a bad idea if it could.  Your "all of them" assumption is shaky

Comment: @ChrisH - Only some of them it is, then!

Answer (score 5):

Tl;Dr; Can it? Absolutely. Will it? Probably not.

Can it contain a virus? Yes. That mouse, like most USB device, has a micro-controller in it. That micro-controller has non-volatile memory. It is likely that that non-volatile memory is writeable (for firmware updates, out of laziness by the designer, it was the cheapest part available that met requirements).

Could it be infected? Yes. Any software that has access to the driver can write to that memory, its likely the software running on the mouse itself would need to be reverse engineered but that would not be that hard.

Could it infect another computer? Yes. The firmware can easily upload a virus for example, it could also so something much more simple, like sending keyboard presses to the target computer.

Is it likely that it's infected? No. All of the above steps are very hard and therefore expensive. No one does hard and expensive work without expecting to earn value. There are two types of hackers, one those that want to make money, they will not attack mice as there are much easier and more profitable attack methods, two "goverment" agencies (think NSA), they want to either collect huge amounts of information (think phone data) or target specific organizations (think stuxnet), that mouse is not common enough for the former or specific enough for the latter.

Answer (score 3):

This mouse will not probably act as a medium for transferring any data or infection unless its bugged with a separate device.
Why?
According to the product specifications:

> 512k in-store memory which macro function can use in different computers

This shows the presence of a storage location of size 512kb, pretty enough for having some infection dropper stored, but not for a very sophisticated one.(Probably directly user accessible memory?)
By new PC, assuming it has everything up-to-date and patched, will be secure also. While this device is connected and the drive is being accessed, surely the security program will scan the 'in-store' memory, which results in detection of infection traces and cleaning it. Well, it depends on the security software installed. That's the case if the memory location is accessible by user/system.

Now, if the memory is not user accessible, ie only the accompanying software has the right to access the memory to manipulate the key mapping data stored in there, probably it only has the right to modify or manipulate the data.
Suppose the infections from the previous system managed to store a dropper in the on-board memory, there must be some actor to trigger the infection to be launched. Since only the companion software can access the memory space, and if it accidentally accessed the dropper, it would not know how to use it and will throw an error.

The narrow case is, the dropper has *specially crafted macro codes*(used by the mouse software) and the software accessed it and tried to make changes according to the macro, you may be infected if those *specially crafted macro* codes can exploit the software and run commands (vb-scripts, for example). (Still the heuristic behavior shield of security software may catch that)

Usually programmable mouse and pointing devices have a separate tool/software to change the functions of various buttons, which must be installed on the machine in which you need to have the intended changes. Same is the case here, but with an on-board storage to reduce the inconvenience of remapping keys while migrating the device.

Macro functions: Macro functions are commands or key combinations being executed by a single button press. Useful for repetitive tasks.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Sharkoon FireGlider mice have their own internal memory which can be written to. These mice could easily contain malicious inputs, I use these to prank friends.

Comment: How do you know mice won't act as a medium?  We look for answers that back up their conclusion with detailed justification, evidence, analysis, and/or reasoning.

Comment: @ D.W I was referring to product mentioned in this topic only, not the advanced cases.

Comment: We still want justifcation.  You just state a conclusion, but you do not provide any evidence, analysis, or details to back up your conclusion.  Saying "I'm only referring to the one product mentioned in the question" is not responsive and does not change the expectation to provide those kinds of details.

Comment: @ D.W. Kindly recheck if that's okay. ☺