# Can a mouse contain viruses?

Tags: virus, hardware, usb

[My mouse dongle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087LXCTFJ) was plugged into a laptop infected with a Trojan Virus, is it a possibility for the mouse dongle to be infected?

Comment: related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100743/can-my-mouse-have-virus-and-infect-other-machines?rq=1

Comment: How do you know the laptop was infected? Do you know what specific "Trojan Virus" the laptop was infected with? Or is this just a hypothetical?

Answer (score 2):

In theory yes, your mouse could be infected.

In practice it is highly unlikely, unless the virus was written with this express intent. You can check behavioral reports on the specific viruses the laptop was infected with on VirusTotal to see if they attempt such things.

Comment: Either the mouse dongle or the mouse or both could be compromised, assuming that both have processors executing firmware from a reprogrammable storage, which for wireless devices is very likely.